# pandas timeseries DF slice and selection

Tags: python, list, datetime, pandas, resampling

I have a df with time series index at 15 minute frequency for 10 years:

```
                        dat
2004-04-07 00:00:00     4.0
2004-04-07 00:15:00     1.0
2004-04-07 00:30:00     2.0
```

I need to be able to extract the min & max 'dat' values per day (0-24 hours) and append them to seperate lists.

My plan was to use an datetime index and loop through like:

```
days = pd.to_datetime(pd.date_range(start = s, end = e, freq='1d'), format='%Y%m%d')

for day in days:
    mn.append(min(df.loc[day].dat))
```

However the timestamps created in 'days' have hours (despite format) so it returns 00:00:00 hour value each time only:

```
2004-04-07 00:00:00     4.0
mn[0] '4.0'
```

Comment: Can't you just `resample('D)` and then call `min` and `max` on this?

Comment: Do'h, yes that should work actually. I was caught up as I need to keep the 15m dat values as they are infact index positions for an nd array. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`Resampler.aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tseries.resample.Resampler.aggregate.html):

```
df = df.resample('D').agg({'dat': ['min','max']})
print (df)
            dat     
            min  max
2004-04-07  1.0  4.0
```

Also:

```
df = df.resample('D')['dat'].agg({'min_dat': 'min', 'max_dat': 'max'})
print (df)
            max_dat  min_dat
2004-04-07      4.0      1.0
```

And if need create lists use [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
Lmin = df.min_dat.tolist()
print (Lmin)
[1.0]

Lmax = df.max_dat.tolist()
print (Lmax)
[4.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
conversion = {'Low': 'min', 'High': 'max'}
minmax= days.resample(rule='1D').apply(conversion)
```